# Checking between two points in an array

Tags: c++

I've got an array that is filled with i elements. I'm wanting to check is something happens between two of them. So far I'm only able to check what happens with one specific element in this array, how can I do it between 2?

My array is filled out like this:

```
int iSegment = pDatagram->header.start - 1;

pdX[0] = (-(pDatagram->distances[0]) * ROD4::dCos_table[0]);
pdY[0] = ( (pDatagram->distances[0]) * ROD4::dSin_table[0]);
iSegment += 1;  //correct start of interval #1

//calculate cartesian values
for(int i = 1 ; i < pDatagram->distanceCount; i++)
{
   pdX[i] = (-(pDatagram->distances[i]) * ROD4::dCos_table[iSegment]);
   pdY[i] = ( (pDatagram->distances[i]) * ROD4::dSin_table[iSegment]);
   iSegment += pDatagram->header.resolution;
}
```

And I'm checking whats happening in the 70th element with the following lines:

```
pdX[70] = (-(pDatagram->distances[70]) * ROD4::dCos_table[70]);
if( pdX[70] > 0 && pdX[70] < 45 ) // these are to test the distances of the 70th element
{
    cout << "My line is broken in the X axis" << endl;
}
```

How would I go about checking to see what happens between the 40th to the 70th element?

Comment: `std::for_each` maybe?

Comment: Though I can get what you have done, I can't understand the last question. What do you mean by 'what happens'. Are you checking if the 'line is broken' across all these points?

Comment: @woosah yeah man. See what I'm doing with the 70th element? I'm wanting to do that with every single element between the 40th and 70th (for example)

Comment: Are you using a C++ container for pdX/pdY or normal C array? are you using C++11 if you're using a std C++ container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following but adapt it to your needs

```
for(int i = 1; i < pDatagram->distanceCount; i++) {

    pdX[i] = (-(pDatagram->distances[i]) * ROD4::dCos_table[iSegment]);
    pdY[i] = ( (pDatagram->distances[i]) * ROD4::dSin_table[iSegment]);
    iSegment += pDatagram->header.resolution;

    if (i <= 70 && i >= 40) {
        if( pdX[i] > 0 && pdX[i] < 45 ) {
            cout << "My line is broken in the X axis" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C-style array, I would simply use a while loop through the required elements from start to finish. Although, I'm still quite unsure what pdX is, it appears to be coordinates with respect to sin/cos (instead of rectangular cartesian form) because you have conditions which require 0 and 45 making me assume you're talking about angles although i'm probably wrong here. please clarify so i may edit this answer

```
size_t x_start = 40;
size_t x_end = 70;

size_t counter = x_start;
bool line_broken_x = false;

while (line_broken_x != false && counter != x_end+1)
{
    if( pdX[counter] < 0 || pdX[counter] > 45 )
        line_broken_x = false;

    counter++;
}

if (line_broken_x == true)
    cout << "My line is broken in the X axis" << endl;
else
    cout << "My line is not broken in the X axis" << endl;
```